# Add vector with CUDA C++ : don't get the expected result

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

I recently started CUDA programming. I followed tutorials and guides about it, and made a first program copied from the original example ( [here pg. 25](https://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-cuda-c-basics.pdf) ), which basically use the GPU to add two vectors.
I can compile it but the result I get isn't the one I expected.

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

//Size of vector
#define N 16


//Kernel for adding vector
__global__ void add(int* a, int* b, int* c){
  c[blockIdx.x] = a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x];
}


//Functions
void printArray(int* a){
  cout << "[ ";
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    cout << *(a+i) << " ";
  } cout << "]" << endl;
}

void fillRandomValue(int* a, int size, int range){
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    *(a+i) = rand() % range;
  }
}


int main(void){
  //Declaration of vector for host and device : a for host ; d_a for device a ;
  int* a,* b,* c;
  int* d_a,* d_b,*d_c;
  int size = N * sizeof(int);

  //Allocate memory into the device
  cudaMalloc((void** )&d_a, size);
  cudaMalloc((void** )&d_b, size);
  cudaMalloc((void** )&d_c, size);

  //Declaring 3 array
  a = new int[size];
  b = new int[size];
  c = new int[size];

  //Randomn array
  //Initialize randomn seed
  srand (time(NULL));
  fillRandomValue(a, N, 10);
  fillRandomValue(b, N, 10);

  //Copy host to device
  cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  //Adding vector
  add<<<N,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);

  //Get back the result
  cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  //Output to console
  cout << "a = "; printArray(a); cout << endl;
  cout << "b = "; printArray(b); cout << endl;
  cout << "a + b = "; printArray(c); cout << endl;

  //Free memory
  free(a); free(b); free(c);
  cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c);

  return 0;

}
```

The problem is I get the following result:

```
a = [ 5 5 7 2 9 5 3 5 4 5 2 9 6 7 4 9 ]

b = [ 9 6 9 8 9 7 5 6 6 6 2 8 7 3 1 2 ]

a + b = [ -971240544 44196 -2117203120 54617 1031799296 65038 1031800320 65038 -2117199280 54617 -1009853744 44196 -1048817168 44196 -1307968288 54865 ]
```

I tried to see if those weren't address, but no.
I also tried to copy the straight code from the link above but I got no luck.

I can reproduce this behavior as much as I want .

Comment: This is incorrect: `cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);` get rid of the ampersand (&).  And likewise for the next line.  You did it correctly on the copy operation after the kernel (where there is no ampersand in front of `c`).  You should also use [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  And just to be clear, although you may have "copied" something from that presentation you linked, you changed it also (compared to what is on slide 25). Those changes matter.

Comment: FYI, there is no C/C++ languages.  C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::vector` and C doesn't.  C++ has templates, inheritance and function overriding, the C language doesn't.  Please update you post title and language tags as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @RobertCrovella ! I didn't see it ( more didn't think of it if it english ). I'm going to mark the question solved thank you.

Comment: I'll correct it thank you @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, the problem was on the `cudeMemcpy(d_a, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)`
The ampersand was not supposed to be here.